# ¿Cómo redireccionar URL no existente a contenido de URL existente?

Tags: .htaccess

He realizado un cambio total en mi sitio web, dividiendo todos los contenidos por idioma, el dominio normal `example.com` mostrará contenido en inglés, el subdominio `es.example.com` mostrará contenido en español.

En el cambio total también modifique URL, en algunas que ya están indexadas.

Necesito poder redireccionar esas URL mediante `.htaccess` 
Por ejemplo:

```
example.com/contenido/la-url-del-producto/
```

Direccionar a:

```
es.example.com/contenido/es/la-url-del-producto/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para redireccionar `URL` antigua puedes hacer uso de `Redirect` donde les indicas dos condiciones, la primera la `URL` antigua y la segunda la `URL` nueva.

Ejemplos:

```
Redirect 301 /contenido/la-url-del-producto/ http://es.example.com/contenido/es/la-url-del-producto/
```

o:

```
Redirect /contenido/la-url-del-producto/ http://http:es.example.com/contenido/es/la-url-del-producto/
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta algo como esto

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/contenido/la-url-del-producto/(.*)$ es.example.com/contenido/es/la-url-del-producto/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Lo probé en localhost con otros directorios y me funcionó.
[Fuente1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416042/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-under-a-folder-to-new-domain) - [Fuente2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408416/redirecting-folder-from-one-domain-to-another-using-htaccess-301-redirect)